# Custom error page for /WEB-INF URI on Tomcat and Spring

Tags: tomcat, redirect

I handle all my 404 errors by a custom Spring error page. This works fine, but there is an exception. The URI /WEB-INF is intercepted by Tomcat first. A default Tomcat error page is shown.

How can I redirect the URI /WEB-INF to an another URI for example /404 or simply prevent Tomcat to intercept it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, its pretty easy. Put this to the `web.xml` file:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404</location>
</error-page>
```